# Preview vhost locally

Tags: apache2

Given that we have an apache vhost, which returns a normal webpage (HTML code), is there any way to get the generated output (i.e. server response) of that specific vhost (i.e. the same HTML code, that the user would see when visiting the webpage via browser) locally on the machine hosting the webpage, without editing any configuration files.

This would be useful for configurations where no incoming traffic is possible on port 80 due to firewall configuration, so wget -O- example.com would not work.

Comment: Why not just requesting the same URL locally?

Comment: Why do you think vhost configuration change would even help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `curl --resolve domain.com:80:127.0.0.1 http://www.domain.com` to request the `domain.com` home page from localhost. The same applies for SSL too, there you need to use `--resolve domain.com:443:127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in the /etc/hosts file.
Where hostname is the vhost name.

```
127.0.0.1   hostname hostname.yourdomain
```

Comment: I don't want/can't edit configurations.